# What is the best way to find all products by id array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies

I am trying to make it possible for an unregistered user to shop.
I use cookies for this.
For the cart view I use:

1. in controller: `@cart_items = cookies[:cart_items].split(',')`
2. in view:

```
<% @cart_items.each do |cart_item| %>
<%= Product.find(cart_item).title %>
<%= Product.find(cart_item).price %>
<% end %>
```

but i think it's not so good.

What is the best way to find all products by id array?

Comment: Views shouldn’t make database queries. Fetch the products in your controller and pass it to your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in controller do this so you are preparing the queried one in the view

controller:

```
@cart_items = Product.where(:id => cookies[:cart_items].split(','))
```

and in the view you do this

```
<% @cart_items.each do |cart_item| %>
<%= cart_item.title %>
<%= cart_item.price %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cookie parsing definitely does not belong in the view. And you should also generally avoid querying the database in the view. The view should ideally just take data from the controller and display it.

Also never use `.find` in a loop. It will create a database query for each iteration. It will also raise a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception if any of the ids where not found in the database.

So:

```
@cart_items = Product.where(id: cookies[:cart_items].split(','))
```

Is less bad. But hardly ideal as it won't let you handle quantities. Instead you could store JSON or create a "guest" Cart record in the database.